# Output average loss on each epoch : weird results

Tags: python, tensorflow

I implemented just a simple model for MNIST data set using Tensorflow.

Here is the model:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
Y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[784, 10], stddev=0.01), name="Weigths")
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,10]), name="Bias")

Y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.add(tf.matmul(X,W), b))
```

Here is how the cost function looks like:

```
entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=Y_, logits=Y)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(entropy)
```

The backprop:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)
```

And here is my train loop:

```
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    avg_loss = 0;
    n_batches = int(MNIST.train.num_examples/batch_size) 
    for i in range(n_batches):
        X_batch, Y_batch = MNIST.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        _, l, summary = sess.run([optimizer, loss, merged_summary], feed_dict={X: X_batch, Y_: Y_batch})
        writer.add_summary(summary, pos)
        avg_loss = l / n_batches
    print('Epoch :', epoch, 'AvgLoss =', avg_loss)
print ("Accuracy:", acc.eval(feed_dict={X: MNIST.test.images, Y_: MNIST.test.labels}))
```

But I don't understand the result of my average cost on each epoch:

```
Epoch : 0 AvgLoss = 0.0028913601962
Epoch : 1 AvgLoss = 0.00283967841755
Epoch : 2 AvgLoss = 0.0028030406345
Epoch : 3 AvgLoss = 0.002759949294
Epoch : 4 AvgLoss = 0.00283429449255
Epoch : 5 AvgLoss = 0.00276749762622
Epoch : 6 AvgLoss = 0.00276815457778
Epoch : 7 AvgLoss = 0.00279549772089
Epoch : 8 AvgLoss = 0.00277937347239
Epoch : 9 AvgLoss = 0.00274000016126
Epoch : 10 AvgLoss = 0.00275734966451
Epoch : 11 AvgLoss = 0.00278236475858
Epoch : 12 AvgLoss = 0.00275594126094
Epoch : 13 AvgLoss = 0.0027651628581
Epoch : 14 AvgLoss = 0.00275661511855
Epoch : 15 AvgLoss = 0.00275890090249
Epoch : 16 AvgLoss = 0.00273716428063
Epoch : 17 AvgLoss = 0.00273372628472
Epoch : 18 AvgLoss = 0.0027502430569
Epoch : 19 AvgLoss = 0.00279064221816
Epoch : 20 AvgLoss = 0.00273178425702
Epoch : 21 AvgLoss = 0.00277335535396
Epoch : 22 AvgLoss = 0.00276518474926
Epoch : 23 AvgLoss = 0.00276605887847
Epoch : 24 AvgLoss = 0.00275481895967
```

It's not reducing each loop... But it gives me a OK accuracy:

```
Accuracy: 0.9295
```

Any ideas on why is it so ?

Comment: could you post your model code as well ?

Comment: @hars edited !!

Comment: To see loss decreasing - print loss for each iteration(each batch) not epoch. Usually , it is reaches minima in few epochs.

Comment: @hars I was inspired by this code : https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/4_Utils/tensorboard_basic.py and when I run it, it works well. What it do is to compute the average loss from each batches in an epoch.

Comment: Yeah, just try running it for 1 epoch and print loss for each batch...you will see the loss going down very fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Loss:** 
To see loss decreasing - print loss for each iteration(each batch) or every 100 iterations not each epoch. Usually , it reaches minima in few epochs.

**Accuracy:**

Use two layer fully connected NN or CNN to get better accuracy. You can add ReLU layers and Dropout for better performance.

2 Layer Fully Connected NN : 96-98% accuracy; ConvNet : 99% accuracy.

To see stats : http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

Also, try his CNN code as well : https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/convolutional_network.py

Comment: I'm not asking about accuracy, I know that I can reach 99% with 2 layers ConvNets.
I tried with only 1 epoch and you're right it decreasing in the first iterations. And then stagnate to 1.5

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud, Sorry for info about Accuracy. Good to know printing iterations helped.

Answer (score 0):

In TensorFlow 2.0 it is quite easy now

```
History = model.fit(trainX,trainY,validation_data = (testX,testY),batch_size= 100, epochs = epochs,verbose = 1)

train_loss = History.history['loss']
val_loss   = History.history['val_loss']
acc = History.history['accuracy']
val_acc = History.history['val_accuracy']
```

when you fit your model store it in a variable. As shown above, you can get loss and accuracy of every epoch and validation loss and accuracy as well.

And you can plot the graph accordingly for

**Loss**

```
plt.plot(History.history['loss'])
plt.plot(History.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Model Loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Test'])
plt.show()
```

**Accuracy**

```
plt.plot(History.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(History.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('Model Accuracy')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Test'])
plt.show()
```